# undefined symbol `MPI_recv'

Tags: c, mpi, compiler-errors

When I link my MPI C program, I get the following error:
`undefined reference to MPI_recv`.

What should i do to solve this error?

Comment: What compiler are you using and what is the OS you are trying to run it on?

Comment: i am using c compiler and its on windows xp.

Comment: wellcome on SO. Please try to be more specific in the title. I edited it, such that it reflects your real question.

Answer (score 13):

It is `MPI_Recv`, not `MPI_recv`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to link to the MPI library that provides the `MPI_recv()` function.  For example, with `gcc`, you would add an option like `-lmpi` to your compile line.

Comment: @High Performance Mark: In that case (boom-boom), there should be another warning about "implicit function definition".  Considering the numerous other missing capital letters in the question ("When", "I", "MPI", "C"), it's possible that the error message wasn't transcribed perfectly.

Comment: The presence of the other warning depends on the compiler being used and the warning settings in use.

Answer (score 0):

MPI implementations usually provide a compilation utility scripts that basically sets up the correct compilation & linking environment, libraries and calls gcc (e.g.) with the correct command line.

Try this:

```
mpicc my_prog.c
```

Hope this helps.

A.